# Adding kankan.wheel into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

How do I add the files here http://android-wheel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ into my Android Studio, so that I can import it and use it in my codes?

I have tried adding it to the app/libs folder and create the dependency on app/build.gradle. It doesn't work.

I would like to do the following:

```
import kankan.wheel.R;
import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelChangedListener;
import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelClickedListener;
import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelScrollListener;
import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.NumericWheelAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this in your `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':app', ':libs:wheel'
```